# How to get the surface from a rect/line

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to find the point where a line collides with a brick in the arkanoid that i am making. The most logical way i found is getting the mask from the line and use collidemask as it returns the point. Well as i tried with this:

```
linemask = pygame.mask.from_surface(pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), bola.line[0], bola.line[1], 2))
```

it gave me this error:

> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect

meaning that the input(in this case the line) can't be a rect but needs to be a surface. Do you know how to get the surface from a rect or any alternative solution ?

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.draw.line`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line) draws on a Surface and returns the affected area in form of a Rect object.

The Surface you drew on is `screen`. So it's `screen` you want to create a mask from. Alternatively, create a new Surface that you use `pygame.draw` on and create a mask from it. Or create a mask from the subsurface of the screen (so you don't have to create a mask from the whole screen), like this:

```
rect = pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), bola.line[0], bola.line[1], 2)
surface = screen.subsurface(rect)
mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(surface)
```