# Check collision between a image and a line

Tags: python, pygame

I check collision:

```
offset = (x0 - x1, y0 - y1)
result = player1.mask.overlap(player2, offset)
```

Its working between two images.

But if I want to check collision between a image and `pygame.draw.line(...)` (I use [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317756/how-to-get-the-surface-from-a-rect-line/42318036#42318036) for create mask from line). `mask.overlap` returns `None`:

```
surface = self.gameDisplay.subsurface(pygame.draw.line(self.gameDisplay, colors.GREEN, [100, 100], [200, 200], 5))
line_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(surface)
pygame.draw.line(self.gameDisplay, colors.GREEN, [100, 100], [200, 200], 5)

offset = (x0 - x1, y0 - y1)
result = player1.mask.overlap(mask, offset)
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to create a surface with per pixel alpha by [`.convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha), before creating the mask from the "line" Surface:

```py
line_rect = pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, colors.GREEN, [100, 100], [200, 200], 5)
line_surf = gameDisplay.subsurface(line_rect)
line_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(line_surf.convert_alpha())

x0, y0 = line_rect.topleft
x1, y1 = player1.rect.topleft

offset = (x0 - x1, y0 - y1)
if player1.mask.overlap(line_mask, offset):
    print("hit : ", count)
```

See the example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-PyGame-SurfaceLineMaskIntersect-1](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SurfaceLineMaskIntersect-1#main.py)</kbd>